# MediaPlayer plays wrong file on first click

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-imagebutton

Can someone point out where I am going wrong with this? When I press the image button it always plays pinktestaudio first even if I did not press the corresponding button. I have to press the image button twice to hear the correct sound.This occurs when the page is first loaded, after the first time it seems fine but still something that shouldn't happen.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;



public class ColorPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Context context = this;
//MediaPlayer mpPurple, mpBlue, mpRed, mpGreen, mpYellow, mpPink;
MediaPlayer media = null;
//private static MediaPlayer media = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_page);

    ImageButton pinkB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pinkButton);
    ImageButton yellowB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yellowButton);
    ImageButton purpleB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.purpleButton);
    ImageButton blueB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
    ImageButton greenB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
    ImageButton redB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redButton);


    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
    purpleB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.blueaudiotest);
    blueB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.blueaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.redaudiotest);
    redB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.redaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.greenaudiotest);
    greenB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.greenaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yellowaudiotest);
    yellowB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.yellowaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
    pinkB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {
                if (media.isPlaying()) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
                }
                media.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Updated: changing the start of the if statement(all of them) to as follows fixed the issue.

```
    if (media != null) {
                    media.stop();
                    media.release();
                    media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always plays `pinktestaudio` because you have done

`media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);`
at the end, so `media` will always be initialized with `pinktestaudio`.
even after you click a different button because in every buttons `OnClickListener` you do

```
if(media.isPlaying()) {
        media.stop();
        media.release();
        media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.pinkaudiotest);
}
```

on clicking any button for first time `media.isPlaying()` will always be false so

`media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.some_audio_file);`

will not be executed.
But when you click again `media.isPlaying()` is true and all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate 6 MediaPlayer instances are created. The last one is used in each of you listeners.

Take a look at your code after refactoring:

```
public class ColorPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_page);

    ImageButton pinkB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pinkButton);
    ImageButton yellowB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.yellowButton);
    ImageButton purpleB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.purpleButton);
    ImageButton blueB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.blueButton);
    ImageButton greenB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.greenButton);
    ImageButton redB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.redButton);

    pinkB.setOnClickListener(this);
    yellowB.setOnClickListener(this);
    purpleB.setOnClickListener(this);
    blueB.setOnClickListener(this);
    greenB.setOnClickListener(this);
    redB.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int audio;

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.pinkButton:
            audio = R.raw.pinkaudiotest;
            break;
        case R.id.yellowButton:
            audio = R.raw.yellowaudiotest;
            break;
        case R.id.purpleButton:
            audio = R.raw.purpleaudiotest;
            break;
        case R.id.blueButton:
            audio = R.raw.blueaudiotest;
            break;
        case R.id.greenButton:
            audio = R.raw.greenaudiotest;
            break;
        case R.id.redButton:
            audio = R.raw.redaudiotest;
            break;
        default:
            audio = R.raw.purpleaudiotest;
    }

    try {
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }

        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), audio);
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have assigned the `media` variable a number of times and the last time it was assigned for `pinkaudiotest` so to solve your problem you have to assign the variable `media` inside the events. So it will be assigned only when a button is clicked.
`.
Here is what you are supposed to do using your own same code:

You have **SIX** lines that looks alike they are of the form of

```
media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
```

Cut those lines and paste them inside the `onClick` method of the corresponding Image Button for example. I am going to do the first one for you and repeat it for all **SIX** times.

```
    purpleB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // I AM ADDING IT HERE
     media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest); //ADDED INSIDE oClick(View view)

        try {
            if (media.isPlaying()) {
                media.stop();
                media.release();
                media = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.purpleaudiotest);
            }
            media.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Repeat that for all **SIX** ImageButton and problem will be gone.